# cannot view pdf in Intellij IDEA

Tags: pdf, intellij-idea, plugins, markdown, pdf-viewer

I am having trouble viewing pdf file (.pdf) in IntelliJ IDEA (ULTIMATE 2019.3) from a markdown file (.md) having ![alt text] clause in it, even after PDFViewer (26th Feb 2013) plugin installed. png is working in there.

viewing pdf by selecting it from Finder on macOS Mojave is always fine but fine from IDEA only if the plugin is disabled.

It seems that the plugin takes extension of '.png' as a default, as viewing png in IDEA is always fine regardless of having '.png' as an extension in the md ![alt text] clause.

any help would be appreciated. Art

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open .pdf files from the external application and not by IDE, check that you have `*.pdf` extension pattern added for Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | File Types -> **Files Opened In Associated Applications**:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment, yet we are talking about 'in place' view of pdf in IDEA with md, as stated above. viewing it externally with Preview on macOS is fine.